# Why my swagger goes on infinite loading when I use Azure service in a Messaging Service class?

Tags: c#, azure, swagger

My swagger goes on infinite loading when I use the Azure service bus class in the messaging service.

Here is the code of the messaging service class:

```
public class MessagingService : IMessagingService
{
    private readonly ILogger<MessagingService> _logger;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;
    private IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
    private readonly IAzServiceBusConsumer _azServiceBusConsumer;

    #region Constructor

    public MessagingService(ILogger<MessagingService> logger,
                            IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory,
                            IMapper mapper,
                            IConfiguration configuration,
                            IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
                            IAzServiceBusConsumer azServiceBusConsumer
        )
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _configuration = configuration;
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        _azServiceBusConsumer = azServiceBusConsumer;
    }
```

Here is the code of `IAzServiceBusConsumer`:

```
namespace Services.Common.Interface
{
    public interface IAzServiceBusConsumer
    {

        void Start();
        void Stop();

        void SendMessage(IntegrationBaseMessage message, string? topicName);

    }
}
```

If I remove the code `private readonly IAzServiceBusConsumer _azServiceBusConsumer;` and also remove `IAzServiceBusConsumer azServiceBusConsumer` from the constructor, the swagger runs just fine.

If the Network tab is checked, it is blank.
[image]

Any help would be more than appreciable.
If any more information is needed, I will add them in the question itself.